# Rails 3.2.3: precompiling assets is failing with "No such file or directory - assets:precompile:all (Errno::ENOENT)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am using rails 3.2.3 and when i run bundle exec rake assets:precompile, it fails with following trace:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace

** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/harish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby /home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/bundler_wrapper assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/bundler_wrapper:22:in `read': No such file or directory - assets:precompile:all (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/bundler_wrapper:22
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/harish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/b...]
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `create_shell_runner'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/harish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/rake:19
/home/harish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/bundler_wrapper:22
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

It is trying to look for the file "assets:precompile:all". When i create a dummy file with the name "assets:precompile:all", it runs successfully but without doing anything. Can somebody please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you run your task under bundler's care? I'm talking about: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: Yes, I ran the command using bundler (bundle exec rake assets:precompile)

Comment: run the bundle exec rake...  with --trace option and post the result,  something is going wrong in an invocation of the sh, like maybe a filename with spaces in it?

Comment: @RadBrad, thank you. I have updated the question with output of --trace option.

Comment: unfortunately,  the --trace isn't making it's way into file_utils.rb,  the output starting with 'Command Failed....'  is still truncated.  There is an answer below,  does that work?

Comment: Look at your various assets,  are there any file names with spaces in the filename?  Also,  you are using Ruby 1.8.7,  but invoking rake.0.9.2.2,  try deleting the rake.0.9.2.2 gem and installing rake.0.9.2,  or if you have both, and need both,  you can try 'exec rake \_0.9.2\_ assets:precompile'

Comment: Thanks RadBrad. The problem was with rake 0.9.2.2. However uninstalling 0.9.2.2 and using 0.9.2 (which was already installed) did not make any difference. After re-installing 0.9.2.2 it started working. Still I am not sure what was the actual issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with rake 0.9.2.2. Re-installing rake 0.9.2.2 fixed the issue.

Comment: Is this issue documented anywhere? Like is it something specifically this version of rake?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well and I resolved it by doing the following:

Open up `config/environments/production.rb` and make sure the following option is set to `true`:

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
```

Then run:

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Shreedhar, thanks for the response. But this solution did not make any difference. The problem still exists.